# jQuery / Ajax simple chatbot, how ignore lowercases

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently programming a simple chatbot but I getting trouble with the input identifier.

```
if (message.indexOf("how are you")>=0){
            send_message("Thanks, Iam good!");
            responsiveVoice.speak("Thanks, Iam good!");
```

Is person is tying in "How are you" the answer will not be triggered since its not lower case. I could copy/paste if state with "How" but is there a easier way? Please be gentle, aim new to programming. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.toLowerCase()`

```
if (message.toLowerCase().indexOf("how are you") >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try toLowerCase function of javascript.

```
messaje.toLowerCase().indexOf("how are you")...
```

Function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp